# How can I eliminate space/margins between two google ads?

Tags: wordpress, adsense

How can I eliminate the spaces between
[these two google ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99F0H.png) to look more like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYewi.png)

I am using wordpress and I'm trying to plug in my ad sense code. I tried different sizes, even the responsive ones but the margins/spaces are always separating the ads.

Here is my ad sense code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-00000000000"
 data-ad-slot="000000"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply float two divs with 50% width each and place your ad code inside.

```css
.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="half">
      place your first ad code here
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      place your second ad code here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

You could additionally set a `min-height: 100px` to `.wrapper` if AdSense can't determine the available height.